# How can I add elements to a list in a specific order?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using JQuery to add elements to a list, it's working but the elements are backwards (for the lack of a better term), and i need to know how can i make them stay in order, instead of = {5,4,3,2,1} should be = {1,2,3,4,5}.

I don't know exactly how to do it, but i hope you guys can help me.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var counter = 0
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#BtnRev").click(function() {
      $("#div1").remove();
    });
    $("#BtnAdd").click(function() {
      counter = counter + 1;
      $("#div2").prepend("<li>", StepTitle.value, Description.value, "  </li>", "Counter>>>", counter, "</br>");
    });
  });
</script>

<br/>
<button type="button" ID="BtnAdd" class="btn btn-basic">Add</button>
<button type="button" ID="BtnAdd2" class="btn btn-warning">Button</button>
<button type="button" ID="BtnRev" class="btn btn-danger">Remove last step (Not yet)</button>
<hr/>
<label for="StepTitle">Title: </label>
<input type="text" id="StepTitle" class="form-control" placeholder="Title..." />
<label for="Description">Description: </label>
<textarea rows="5" id="Description" class="form-control"></textarea>
<hr />
<script src="Test2.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <p>This is meant to be deleted</p>
</div>
<div class="well">
  <h4>Things go here!</h4>
  <ol id="div2">
    <!---->
  </ol>
</div>
```

As i explained before, the output that i'm getting is {5,4,3,2,1} and should be {1,2,3,4,5}... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to prepend the values to the list when you should be appending to the list. Append will add the term to the end of the list to maintain the order you want.

Change the line

```js
 $("#div2").prepend("<li>", StepTitle.value, Description.value, "  </li>", "Counter>>>", counter , "</br>");
```

to

```js
 $("#div2").append("<li>", StepTitle.value, Description.value, "  </li>", "Counter>>>", counter , "</br>");
```

and you should see the expected output. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Change `prepend` to `append`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var counter = 0
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#BtnRev").click(function() {
      $("#div1").remove();
    });
    $("#BtnAdd").click(function() {
      counter = counter + 1;
      $("#div2").append("<li>", StepTitle.value, Description.value, "  </li>", "Counter>>>", counter, "</br>");
    });
  });
</script>

<br/>
<button type="button" ID="BtnAdd" class="btn btn-basic">Add</button>
<button type="button" ID="BtnAdd2" class="btn btn-warning">Button</button>
<button type="button" ID="BtnRev" class="btn btn-danger">Remove last step (Not yet)</button>
<hr/>
<label for="StepTitle">Title: </label>
<input type="text" id="StepTitle" class="form-control" placeholder="Title..." />
<label for="Description">Description: </label>
<textarea rows="5" id="Description" class="form-control"></textarea>
<hr />
<script src="Test2.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <p>This is meant to be deleted</p>
</div>
<div class="well">
  <h4>Things go here!</h4>
  <ol id="div2">
    <!---->
  </ol>
</div>
```

**Note**:
The `.prepend()` method inserts the specified content as the first child of each element in the jQuery collection (To insert it as the **last** child, use `.append()`).